# Deserialize Json with same Label

Tags: c#, json

Hey i would like to deserialize my json i get from a webrequest.

The problem ive got is that i have the same lable "id" I need to get the ID from the attachment and the id from the Source. Both got the name "id"

my json looks like this:

```
"data": [{
    "id": 45,
    "file_name": "test.pdf",
    "description": "",
    "attach_date": "2017-11-23T12:18:18Z",
    "source": {
        "id": 62,
        "source_type": "features"
    },
    "created_by": {
        "id": 100,
        "user_type": 0
    }
```

my code dont work cause i use the same lable in json property "id"

my class looks like:

```
    public class Attachment
{
    [JsonProperty("id")] public int AttachmentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("file_name")] public string FileName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")] public int SourceId { get; set; }
}
```

is there a way i could change the json property to get the id from source:?

Sorry in advance im still a beginner in programming.

Comment: It's a subclass, you should treat it that way.  Paste your raw JSON into jsonutils.com and it will give you the classes.

Comment: wow, i guess it was to simple. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume SourceId in your Attachment class is the id of source object in Your response.
In such case You should create another class to represent the source

```
    public class Attachment
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")] public int AttachmentId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("file_name")] public string FileName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("source")] public SourceEntity Source { get; set; }
    }
    public class SourceEntity
    {
        [JsonProperty("source_type")] public string SourceType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")] public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

If You still want to access SourceId in Attachment class you can add

```
public int SourceId { get => Source.Id; }
```

to Attachment class